# Graph spanning tree proof

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $C^*$ be a set of edges of a connected graph $G$. Show that if $C^*$ has an edge in common with each spanning tree of $G$, then $C^*$ contains a cutset.
>
> Obtain a corresponding result for cycles.

How could I begin this proof?

Comment: Suppose on the  contrary that $C^*$ contains no cut-set.
Then $G - C^*$ is still connected.  Thus $G - C^*$ has a spanning tree...the rest is up to you.  I don't get the corresponding result for cycles.  Can you state it fully ?

Answer (score 2):

Each edge in a spanning tree is a cut edge. That is, if $e$ is a cut-edge of $T$, then $T - \{e\}$ leaves $T$ disconnected. A cut set $K$ is a set of edges such that $E(G) - K$ will leave $G$ disconnected. So what happens if we remove an edge from each spanning tree of $G$? Won't that leave $G$ disconnected?